# MVC Razor view - currency formatting

Tags: razor, model-view-controller

I am using razor syntax. I have value e.g. 1123456 returned to my view.
I would like to show it like **$1,123,456 USD**.

I have following line

```
@Model.TotalCost
```

How I can apply a string format on it to show a value like $1,123,456 USD?

Comment: string.Format("{0:C}", @Model.TotalCost) USD

Comment: Is that the way correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `string.Format` as you mention or, more simply, provide the currency format to the `ToString()` method of the property:

```
  @Model.TotalCost.ToString("C") USD
```

Comment: With "C" the currency symbol is already included.

Example: 
`decimal value = 16325.62m;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
// Displays:    $16,325.62`